# Need help with C# ParseExact syntax and moving between timezones

Tags: c#, datetime

Okay, I have decided to let the magic of Stackoverflow work for me!

I have a date in the format: "Apr 18 2011 19:30 EDT" that I need to push into a DateTime object in C#. One caviat, I also want to shift it to UTC too. Obivisouly when DST is over it'll come over as EST.

I know that I need a statement like:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("Apr 18 2011 19:30 EDT",  "MMM DD yyyy something something ",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate);
```

But getting it over to UTC is above my knowlwedge level.

So in summary, I need:

1. To turn Apr 18 2011 19:30 EDT into a DateTime
2. Convert the EDT timezone to UTC time.
3. End up with a DateTime object.

What's the code, wizards?

Comment: ah ha, I didn't know that was importante. I do now and I shall!

Comment: It's a normal Wenesday here. Wife is calling from home because one of the smoke detectors starting beeping and won't stop after she replaced the battery... The 4 yr old bit her playfully but she's also hormonal... so it's a mess! I just couldn't think all this out!

Comment: From what timezone is your string coming?  That is: are you in CDT, for instance? Or GMT?  If you're already in the Eastern time zone, I think the DateTime object auto-magically handles conversion from CDT to "real" time.

Comment: @AllenG, hehehe that's the best part. Some of the machines in our DEV env are on UTC and some of them in PROD are in local DST time. So I never trust the machines' timezone setting. I know the input is coming in either as EDT or EST and I want to go to UTC. So I stay away from the LocalTime methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's *always* going to be in Eastern Daylight Time, you can do something like:

```
// Parse string. We don't need escaping since E,D and T 
// are not considered special characters by ParseExact.
var dateTimeInEasternTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Apr 18 2011 19:30 EDT",
                                                "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm EDT",    
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Convert from the relevant timezone to UTC.
var dateTimeInUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime
                    (dateTimeInEasternTime,  
                     TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"), 
                     TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

You can cache the `TimeZoneInfo` representing EST (which becomes EDT while daylight savings is on) to prevent the lookup.

If the string could end with a three letter code representing some *arbitrary* time-zone, it's going to be a lot more difficult since there are many conventions for them, none of which (AFAIK) are currently supported by .NET. Your best bet would be to first build a lookup from the code to the relevant `TimeZoneInfo` (perhaps through the `Id` property) after which you can do the conversion with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` as usual.

Comment: Awsome, I think this is it. How do you Cache the TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: @Paul: One way would be with a static read-only field in the class that contains this method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where you're getting hung up. It sounds like you have successfully parsed the string into a `DateTime`.

To convert the value to UTC, call the `ToUniversalTime()` method. Note that this will assume the current time value is relative to your system's current time zone.

`ToUniversalTime()` converts to a `DateTime` value.